# CSS & HTML: Spacing content at the beginning and end of table row issues

Tags: html, css

I have been driving myself crazy, wondering how to do this.
I have a table. at one end of the table row i want my product description and the other end my product price and add to cart button. With nothing in-between.
However, i can not get this to work right now without using endless new table row tags, which i do not want do to.

**What i have tried:**

- Margin right
- padding

I cannot use border spacing or cellspacing as i only want this to happen on 1 out of 2 of my table rows. any suggestions?...

```css
td.spacing{
    margin-right: 30%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td><p id='prods_nme'>$prod_name</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='spacing'><p id='prods_desc'>$prod_desc</p></td>
<td></td>
                                  
<td class='spacing' rowspan='2'><p id='prods_price'>£$prod_price</p></td>
<td><a href='Shopping_cart.php?add_item=$prod_id'>+</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**I would like it to look like this:**

[image]

Comment: Try using float : right and float left

Comment: An image of how this is supposed to look would be more use.

Comment: @Paulie_D image added

Comment: @Rahul that doesn't work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overthinking this.

You don't need extra rows.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
table td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
table td.full {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="full">
      <p id='prods_nme'>My Product</p>
      <p id='prods_desc'>My Product Desription</p>
    </td>
    <td class="price">
      <p id='prods_price'>£10.00</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="full">
      <p id='prods_nme'>My Product</p>
      <p id='prods_desc'>My Product Desription</p>
    </td>
    <td class="price">
      <p id='prods_price'>£10.00</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```